# How to use WGLARB in LWJGL 3?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, game-engine

Previously in my game engine written in java, I have used lwjgl 2.9.3.  I ran into an issue.  I wanted lwjgl to run on another graphics card.  So I researched and soon figured out, that it would be impossible using lwjgl 2.9.3.  So I read about seeing if lwjgl's developers were going to add the option of choosing which graphics card you get to run on.  I figured out that lwjgl 3 did have support for this.  So I switched over to lwjgl 3.
  I got everything working and started to work on why I switched.  I soon figured out that there is no documentation for changing which graphics card you use.  So after hours of testing I figured out that you need to create a WGLARB context. 
 I know you can just use the method: `wglCreateContextAttribsARB(long hdc, long sharedContext, Byte/IntBuffer attribList)`.  But it is unclear how to use this method.  I am not sure if you use the windows DC Pointer or something else.  I know you do not have to put anything in for the '`long sharedContext`' so I put '`MemoruUtil.NULL`'.  So here are my questions:

1. How do you create a WGLARB context, or more specificly what do you specifically pass in, like do you put in an empty Int/Byte Buffer or do you put data into the buffer before you pass it in as a parameter.  I do not know.
2. From there how do you use: `WGLNVGPUAffinity.getInstance().wglCreateAffinityDCNV(gpuList);` GPU list is either a PointBuffer or ByteBuffer how do I get this data to pass in in the first place?

Sorry about the long post, but I am very frustrated about the lack of documentation, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

LWJGL 3 (through GLFW) handles OpenGL context creation. Which means you *don't* get to handle it. GLFW will create the context, though it does give you some options as to exactly how. But GLFW is cross-platform, so it doesn't give you Windows & NVIDIA-specific options.

However, that doesn't mean you don't get some control. LWJGL 3 also gives you access to the platform-specific APIs (GLX, WGL, etc), as well as extensions to them. So you can use `WGL.wglGetCurrentContext` to get the context, then use the [WGLNVGPUAffinity functions](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/WGLNVGPUAffinity.html) to create affinity contexts. [That extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/gpu_affinity.txt) provides all of the various tools for enumerating GPUs and creating new OpenGL contexts that target a specific GPU.

The extension specification is even nice enough to provide sample code for enumerating GPUs. Of course, it's NVIDIA only, but that clearly isn't a problem for you.